# rails assest:precomplie , when load file not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I have web RoR, I ran assets:precomplie, and i got file

```
**/application-dfaaca6b25e0d101d80f81c5cb194f6d39d331886613c0a392283b01b9911cb0.css**
```

but my web was loaded another file

```
**application.self-a429e1a197d1ad3e5a775f50a60fd344db3ba490db151ab8c7494a78cba792a2.css**.
```

i don't know reason. Anybody, can help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I got the same questions. then finally I find the answer:

when you process `assets:precomplie`, you must specify the env as you run rails, because in different enviroments, the assets version is not same!

1. when you run rails in development env as `rails s`, you should process as `rake assets:precomplie` or `assets:precomplie RAILS_ENV=development`
2. when you run rails in production env as `rails s -e p`, you should process as `rake assets:precomplie RAILS_ENV=production`

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks your support. assets:precomplie with RAILS_ENV is ok, but i don't know why all files added ".self" (application.self-a429e1a197d1ad3e5a775f50a60fd344db3ba490db151ab8c7494a78cba792a2.css).

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Deploy your application again

if still not solved

- SSH into the system
- delete the file `your_app/manifest_backup`
- `$ bundle exec rake assets:clear`
- `$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
- restart the webserver ( for Nginx `/etc/init.d/nginx` restart or `$ sudo service nginx restart` )
  if still not solved deploy your app again

For more info see my blog
https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/ruby-on-rails-production-staging-when-asset-path-is-outdated/

Comment: https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/ruby-on-rails-production-staging-when-asset-path-is-outdated/ -> that's great. Thank you alot :-x

Comment: @thienhv if this works, don't forget to up-vote to notify future visitors :)